# Convert Unix time in Django Template

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Attempting to make unix time in a Django template human readable with formatting.  Have the following template code:

```
<ul>
   {% for i in forecast %}
       <li>{{ i.time|date:"D d M Y" }}, {{i.temperature}}, {{i.dewPoint}}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This (and any other) formatting I attempt are returning the following error from Google App Engine:

```
<li>{{ i.time|date:"D d M Y" }}, {{i.temperature}}, {{i.dewPoint}}</li>
    TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'
```

Incidentally, removing the formatting (|date:"D d M Y") renders the full list successfully, just with unix time.

I'm stumped, hoping the good folks in the Stackoverflow community can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which django version is this?

Comment: Also is `i.time` a datetime object?

Comment: The django version is 1.5.1.  i.time references a key located in a list of dicts created by: forecast = json.loads(data).  I have verified that the value of the i.time key is an int.